# Adding name to input field using SQL database field

Tags: php, html, sql

So what I'm trying to do is add a `name='' value` to an `option` in a drop down list. This all is pretty simple using just HTML. But I would like to have the `name value` be from the database I'm queuing. But the database string has `spaces` in between the words, and this causes a problem. I need the string to be `Eten & drinken` and not the way it outputs now, see example below.

Right now, I've got this:

```
   <?php $q = $row["Categorie"];
        echo    "   
            <option value=".$q." name=".$q.">
               ".$row["Categorie"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   <span style='font-size:1.2rem;color:#F8F8F8;'>(" . $row['x'] .  ")
                   </span>
            </option>
    ";?>
```

Which outputs the following if I look at the source:

```
<option value="eten-en-drinken" name="Eten" &amp;="" drinken="">
    Eten &amp; drinken&nbsp;&nbsp;(19)
</option>
```

I've tried searching google and `str_replace`, `htmlspecialchars`, `utf8_encode` and changed `name` to `data-type` but noting works. I just want it to be `Eten en drinken`. I need this exact value for use in a second drop down menu. Any thoughts, documentation or help?

Comment: close the php tag after `$q = $row["Categorie"];`

Comment: Sorry, forgot the PHP tags... updated my question. The SELECT * etc is outside this file, but that all works correct. The `$row's` are shown correct and the data is queued, only the `name=''` part is the problem here.

Comment: this is weird. in your php, you do not have name and value attributes

Comment: @Akin What do you mean? (I just made an other update, forgot to change the name value back, oops). How about now? The `$stub` value was the same as the name value. So I changed that, hope this is better and clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem migh be solved by adding missing quotes for `name` attribute.

```
echo    "   
        <option value=".$q." name='".$q."'>..."
```

Comment: Riiiiightttttt. Now I feel kind of stupid. But this was it. Thank man!

Comment: No problem, it can be confusing with all the quotes :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

$q = $row["Categorie"];

echo "< option value=".$stub." name=".$q." > ".$row["Categorie"]." < span style='font-size:1.2rem;color:#F8F8F8;'>(" . $row['x'] .  ")< /span>< /option>";

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) when saving your data to mySQL and not when retrieving it-

```
<?php
  $new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
  echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
?>
```

When retrieving your data, try using [htmlspecialchars_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)-

```
<?php
  $str = "<p>this -&gt; &quot;</p>\n";
  echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);

  // note that here the quotes aren't converted
  echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str, ENT_NOQUOTES);
?>
```