# Dropdown only saves and then display's first value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So to continue my last question [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495996/adding-name-to-input-field-using-sql-database-field). I've finally got that sorted out (with help), but now the value of the name is only the first value of the drop down list.

A brief explanation, I have 2 drop down menu's and when you select a option from one (A) the other drop down menu is updated (B). I know it has something to do with an `array` but I can't figure this out.

Here are my files.

**HTML**

```
<select id="main_cat" name="main_cat">
    <option selected="-1" select="selected">Select something</option>

    <?php 
        $sttub = str_replace('&', 'en', $stub);
        $q = $row["Categorie"];
            echo "
            <option class='dropdownmenu_A' value='".$sttub."' name='".$q."'>"
                .$row["Categorie"]."
                    <span style='font-size:1.2rem;color:#F8F8F8;'>
                        (" . $row['x'] .  ")
                    </span>
            </option>
        ";
    }}?>
</select>
<select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat" disabled="disabled"></select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
    $('#main_cat').change(function(){
            var $mainCat=$('#main_cat').val();
            var $mainName = $(".dropdownmenu_A").attr("name");
            // call ajax
             $("#sub_cat").empty();
                $.ajax({
                url:"<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",     
                type:'POST',
                data:'action=my_special_ajax_call&main_catid=' + $mainCat + '&main_name=' + $mainName,

                success:function(results)
                       {
                        //  alert(results);
                        console.log($mainCat,$mainName);
                        $("#sub_cat").removeAttr("disabled");       
                          $("#sub_cat").append(results);
                        }
                   });
          }
    );
});
```

**function.php**

```
function implement_ajax() {
if(isset($_POST['main_catid']))
            {
            $q = $_POST['main_catid'];
            $x = $_POST['main_name'];
            echo '<option value="-1" selected="selected">'.$x.'</option>'.$option;
            die();
            } // end if
}
```

I have tried using `<select id="main_cat" name="main_cat[]">` like I found on google but this didn't work. Using `$x[] = $_POST['main_name'];` just echos the word `Array`. How do I get this to work and display the correct option that is selected and not just the first every time.

To be clear, here are my drop down menu's (sometimes my brain goes faster then I can type, so I hope it's clear).

```css
select{height:30px}
```

```html
<select id="main_cat" name="main_cat">
 <option selected="-1" select="selected">Select something</option>
  <option class='dropdownmenu_A' value='option-1' name='Option 1'>
  <option class='dropdownmenu_A' value='option-2' name='Option 2'>
  <option class='dropdownmenu_A' value='option-2' name='Option 2'>
</select>
<select id="sub_cat" name="sub_cat">
 <option selected="-1" select="selected">Select something</option>
  <option class='dropdownmenu_B' value='sub-option-1' name='Sub Option 1'>
  <option class='dropdownmenu_B' value='sub-option-2' name='Sub Option 2'>
  <option class='dropdownmenu_B' value='sub-option-2' name='Sub Option 2'>
</select>
```

So right now if I select Option 1 from dropdownmenu_A it only echo's the first value from dropdownmenu_A to dropdownmenu_B and not Option 2 or Option 3.

Comment: Is there suppose to be a loop somewhere in your HTML? Why is there trailing `}}` ?

Comment: Yeah, there is a SELECT * FROM SQL query above the code, but that all works fine. I think I got the most important part. Oh and yeah, if I post that in the question people will first tell me that my code is vulnerable to SQL injection :). And I know it is right now, but the code is running on my own machine, so I'm doing both at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You can't have `<span/>` tags inside `<option/>` tags as the latter cannot have any child elements.

2- `<option/>` doesn't have a `name` attribute. If you want to create a custom attribute, use [HTML5 data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). That's what they are for.

3- [printf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) is your new friend.

```
printf('<option class="dropdownmenu_A" value="%s" data-name="%s">%s (%s)</option>', $sttub, $q, $row["Categorie"], $row['x']);
```

4- I believe the problem is `$(".dropdownmenu_A").attr("name")` as this would always pull the same name and not the selected name. In your particular case, I would do

```
$(function(){
    $('#main_cat').change(function(){
        var $option = $(this).find('option:selected'),
            id = $option.val(),
            name = $option.data('name');

        // open your browser's console log and ensure that you get the correct values
        console.log(id, name);

        $("#sub_cat").empty();

        // call ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",     
            type:'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'my_special_ajax_call',
                main_catid: id,
                main_name: name
            },
            success: function (results) {
                $("#sub_cat").removeAttr('disabled').html(results);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, almost there I think. The `printf` (my new friend) isn't nice to me. It only prints `()` now? I copied your code exactly also the function works. Thanks! And I also changed the `name` to `data-name`.

Comment: Still issues? If so, is the console log showing the correct values after selecting different options? If so, then I would look at your browser's network tab to see what is being sent and what is being sent back. This could (doubt it) be a caching issue.

Comment: Still issues. I checked `console.log` which is showing the correct values after selecting the different options. Also the network tab is doing the AJAX requests correct. It seems like it doesn't know what to do with the `printf`.

Comment: I've fixed the issue with the `()`. And I know what the problem is. The AJAX request is done using the `functions.php` file of wordpress BUT the `functions.php` file does not have a connection with the database I'm connected to with the `dropdown.php` file. So it doesn't know what data to show. Is there away to make a database connection in the function you posted above?

Comment: Yeah, I fixed it myself. :) got the database to work inside the function. Thanks for getting me in the right direction!

Answer (score -3):

You should add a selected attribute to your selected option:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Comment: That, doesn't seem to work. And I don't think that's what I'm looking for. My drop down menu works. But only the first option in my drop down is selected. If I select the other values it just shows the first value again.

Comment: Did you provide the negative review? :) The problem is you don't print selected attribute after the site reload, so the solution is still there :)

Comment: I never give negative reviews to people who take the time to read and comment on my questions. Could you elaborate on your comment.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. And didn't you have a different name yesterday?

Comment: Understand :) I started this behave when I saw another user with tentousands reputation did it same... Yes, I saw yesterday the site pulled my nickname from facebook, i changed to my personal name, because this way users can see, I'm open minded guy :) That's why my photo remain the same. Any very important question or advice?

Comment: @Jay-oh: So , i think the problem is, when php returns with your ajax response html you always add selected attribute, instead of the one select what you would like to see like selected option: echo '<option value="-1" selected="selected">'.$x.'</option>'

Comment: @Peter you where right, I think. I edited this: `var $mainName = $(".dropdownmenu_1").attr("name");` to this `var $mainName = $(".dropdownmenu_1:selected").attr("name");` now it kind of works. Only I have the same problem as in my link in the question :) It cuts the words off (stops when a space is there)...

Comment: @Jay-oh Paste here the generated html source code please, or if you can show me the site wold be more better